# Displaying data from a certain database field that a user enters into a search bar

Tags: javascript, php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have some code where the intended purpose is a user typing into a search bar. Upon searching, a table should display with records closely related to the search phrase. In my case, I have all the code set up, but I am not getting any table being shown upon searching.

I have many lines commented out and those are some of the fixes and things I have messed around with that I thought would fix this.

The Search function code - search.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ProfessorsOrStaff where Name LIKE '%".$name."%'";

//echo $sql;
$data = array();
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//echo json_encode($result);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['Name'];
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
} else {
    //array_push($data);
    echo "no data";
    exit;
}
//array_push($data, {"msg":'success'});
echo json_encode($data);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Partial code of file that displays the search bar and javascript

```
<div id="message" style="text-align: center">
        <p>There are no results.</p>
    </div>
    <table class="table" id="result_table" hidden="hidden">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="body">
            <tr>
                <!--<td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>-->
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#search").click(function(){
    var text = $("#name").val();
    $.post('search.php', {name: text}, function(data){

        console.log(data);
        //$name = $_POST['name'];
        if(data != "no data" ){
            console.log("here");
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            //$("#result_table").setAttr('hidden');
            $('#result_table').removeAttr('hidden');
            $("#message").hide();
            var html = '';
            for(var i = 0 ; i < obj.length; i ++ ){
                console.log(obj[i]);
                html += '</td><td>'+obj[i].Name+'</td><td>'+obj[i].PhoneNumber+'</td></tr>';
            }
            $('#body').html(html);
        }
        else{
            $('#result_table').attr("hidden","hidden");
            $("#message").show();
        }
    });
})
```

The code is a bit messy. To clarify, 
The search.php can be found here-https://codeshare.io/a3wdmD

Other file with javascript- https://codeshare.io/G8838A

Table layout -https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS22P.jpg

EDIT1- After finding out the request was not being made, I switched some stuff around and was able to make it not correctly call the search.php file. Now I am getting the wrong results from this. It is bringing me to a new page and displaying the contents of all my records in that table, as a plain text format. I was trying to make it so once the search button was pressed, a table of results appeared right below the search bar. The links to the full code have been updated to show the current state of the code.

Comment: A first step would be to check your browser's Network tab (in dev tools) to see if the request was sent correctly, and see what response you got.

Comment: @AnisR. I checked the tab and do not see anything that would signify that a request was even sent. SO this would be a connecting problem to the database? Or a problem with the way the PHP request is made?